# Nginx server config optimisation using image_filter and proxy_cache

Tags: nginx, configuration, server

I have the nginx server config file below setup and working fine, but I wondered if there is a way of optimising it so there isn't as much repetition with the proxy settings.

I want to restrict the resizing that can be done to specific pre-set dimensions, rather than allowing `/resized/200x100/image.jpg` for example.

I'm serving these images via Ghost, so I can only prepend or append the URL.

```
upstream backend {
    server domain.name;
}

proxy_cache_path /var/www/cache/resized levels=1:2 keys_zone=resizedimages:10m max_size=1G;

server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/domain/source;

    server_name domain.name;

    image_filter_buffer 10M;
    image_filter_jpeg_quality 85;

    proxy_store_access user:rw group:rw all:rw;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;

        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location ~ /resize/xs/(.*) {
        proxy_pass http://backend/$1;

        proxy_cache resizedimages;
        proxy_cache_valid 200 1d;
        proxy_cache_valid any 1m;
        proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header updating;

        image_filter resize 320 -;
    }

    location ~ /resize/xs@2x/(.*) {
        proxy_pass http://backend/$1;

        proxy_cache resizedimages;
        proxy_cache_valid 200 1d;
        proxy_cache_valid any 1m;
        proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header updating;

        image_filter resize 480 -;
        image_filter_jpeg_quality 65;
    }

    location ~ /resize/sm/(.*) {
        proxy_pass http://backend/$1;

        proxy_cache resizedimages;
        proxy_cache_valid 200 1d;
        proxy_cache_valid any 1m;
        proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header updating;

        image_filter resize 480 -;
    }

    location ~ /resize/sm@2x/(.*) {
        proxy_pass http://backend/$1;

        proxy_cache resizedimages;
        proxy_cache_valid 200 1d;
        proxy_cache_valid any 1m;
        proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header updating;

        image_filter resize 720 -;
        image_filter_jpeg_quality 65;
    }

    # md, m@2x, etc.

    location ~ /resized/(sq/xs|sq/md|xs|xs@2x|sm|sm@2x|md|md@2x|lg|lg@2x|xl|xl@2x)/(.*) {
        try_files /resize$1/$2 @img;
    }

    location @img {
        proxy_pass http://backend/resize/$1/$2;
        proxy_store /var/www/domain/cache/$1/$2;
    }
}
```